# Customise grid view in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, cgridview

How to remove summary and sorter for a particular grid view in Yii2. In Yii1.1 we can do that by setting the template property. In yii2 how to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it.By setting the layout property,we can achieve it.

```
'layout'=>"{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}"
```

Answer (score 47):

To change only `summary` option, you can use:

```
'summary' => "{begin} - {end} {count} {totalCount} {page} {pageCount}",
```

Then, if you want to empty `summary` set with empty string value like:

```
'summary'=> "",
```

and to change layouts you can use:

```
'layout'=> "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}"
```

Then, if you want to empty `layouts` set layout with empty string value like:

```
'layout'=> "",
```

[Ref link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$summary-detail)

[Ref link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$layout-detail)

So, for sample, i think bellow sample code can be help know how to change and custome `GridView` table in Yii 2:

```
                <?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
                'id' => 'table',
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'layout'=>"{sorter}\n{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}",
                'summary' => "Showing {begin} - {end} of {totalCount} items",
                'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table  table-bordered table-hover'],
                'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                    return [
                        'style' => "cursor: pointer",
                        'onclick' => 'location.href="'
                            . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('test/index')
                            . '?id="+(this.id);',
                    ];
                },
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 20px;', 'class' => 'text-center'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'attribute' => 'date',
                        'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
                        'label' => 'Date',
                        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 130px;', 'class' => 'text-center'],
                    ],
                        'template' => '{view}',
                        'buttons' => [
                            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                return \yii\helpers\Html::a('<div class="text-center"><em data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                            data-placement="top" title="more detail"
                                                            class="fa fa-external-link-square text-warning"></em></div>',
                                    (new yii\grid\ActionColumn())->createUrl('test/index', $model, $model['id'], 1), [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'view'),
                                        'data-method' => 'post',
                                        'data-pjax' => '0',
                                    ]);
                            },
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

Comment: Error-  Undefined variable: count.  $dataProvider->count fixed that for me.

Comment: 'count' come from controller that passed on view render, You can remove 'count' variable.

Answer (score 6):

if you want only grid items use `'layout'=>"{items}"`

if you want only summary use `'layout'=>"{summary}"`

if you want only sorter use `'layout'=>"{pager}"`

Answer (score 0):

Set the paremeter `summaryText` to empty string:

```
array(
    'summaryText' => '',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
...
```

Comment: that gives me an unknown property exception! Its yii2! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'buttons' =>
        [
            'update'=>function($url,$model,$key)
            {
                return Html::a( "update" , $url ); //use Url::to() in order to change $url
            },
            'view'=>function($url,$model,$key)
            {
                return Html::a( "update" , $url ); //use Url::to() in order to change $url
            },
            'delete'=>function($url,$model,$key)
            {
                return Html::a( "update" , $url, [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',
                    'data' => [
                        'method' => 'post',
                        'params' => ['derp' => 'herp'], // <- extra level
                    ],
                ] ); //use Url::to() in order to change $url
            }
        ],
    'template' => '<div class="column-buttons">
                                        <span>{update}</span>
                                        <span>{view}</span>
                                        <span>{delete}</span>
                                    </div>',
    'header' => 'Actions'
]
```